# How to login to Spotify with username and password?

Tags: android, authentication, spotify

As the question goes, I want to login into Spotify in Android using the username and password. **I don't want to login using the App or the embeded web view** to make my app cleaner. I'm using my own GUI to try the login.

Is there a way to do so? I'm not very familiar with the API calls but I can't find a way.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the Spotify API. This is the main flow:

```
Session session = new Session();

    try {
        String response = "";
        URL url = new URL(GET_TOKEN_URL);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(POST);

        String credentials = params[0]+":"+params[1];
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), credentials);
        String basicAuth ="Basic "+new String(android.util.Base64.encode(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), basicAuth);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(AUTH,basicAuth);
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                .appendQueryParameter(GRANT_TYPE, CLIENT_CREDENTIALS);

        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

        OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(query);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        httpURLConnection.connect();

        int responseCode=httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

        session.setResponseCode(responseCode);

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }
        }else;{
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "ERROR:" + responseCode);
            response = "Something went wrong";
        }
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), response);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{

    }
    return session;
```

Please note that Session is just a Class to hold the response code.